# User-mode synchronization vs. kernel mode synchronization (in Linux and Windows)

Tags: linux, windows, multithreading, kernel-mode

I have 2 questions about user mode synchronization and kernel mode synchronization.

First: What is user mode synchronization and kernel mode synchronization?

Second: What is differences between user-mode synchronization and kernel mode synchronization in Linux and Windows?

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Threads in User and kernel mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515676/threads-in-user-and-kernel-mode)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515676/threads-in-user-and-kernel-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs are written to solve problems. To execute a program, the operating system creates a process for that program. A process executes a program. By default, a process executes in the user mode. A process may need to use resources, like the hard disk or the network connection, that are shared by *all* the processes in the system. Or, it might need to do some privileged operation like change its priority. In other words, it needs help from 
*someone*, who has overall access for the system. Then by some mechanism, it goes into the kernel mode from the user mode to do such operations. One such operation is synchronization - both for processes and threads. Synchronization is done using semaphores. For more details, refer to the link, [Semaphore Basics](http://www.softprayog.in/programming/semaphore-basics).